# Why can a partition bound expression not include a casting operation?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

In the [Postgres CREATE TABLE docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtable.html), creating a partition of a table is described like this:

> `PARTITION OF parent_table { FOR VALUES partition_bound_spec | DEFAULT }`
>
> ...
>
> `partition_bound_expr` is any variable-free expression (subqueries, window functions, aggregate functions, and set-returning functions are not allowed). Its data type must match the data type of the corresponding partition key column. The expression is evaluated once at table creation time...

So why is this a syntax error?

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo
(ts timestamptz)
PARTITION BY RANGE(ts)
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo_1970_01_01
PARTITION OF foo
FOR VALUES
  FROM ('1970-01-01 00:00+00:00'::timestamptz)
  TO ('1970-02-01 00:00+00:00'::timestamptz)
;
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"
LINE n: FROM ('1970-01-01 00:00+00:00'::timestamptz)
                                      ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using PostgreSQL v11 or older.

Back then, it could only be a literal:

> `FROM ( { numeric_literal | string_literal | TRUE | FALSE | MINVALUE | MAXVALUE } [, ...] )`

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html).

Comment: Gah! Yes, I'm using Postgres 11. Silly me for looking at the wrong docs!